# Exchange 2016, Can't add Send Connector

Tags: exchange

Just trying to set up exchange 2016 at home on winserv 2012 r2 just to try it out before deploying it at work. And i've run into a bit of an annoying problem.

Following microsofts guide for adding a send connector, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218640(v=exchg.160).aspx
I get up to Step 8 "Under Source server, click Add Add icon. In the Select a Server window, select a Mailbox server. After you've selected the server, click Add and then click OK."

But neither the "Ok" or "Cancel" buttons respond to my mouse click.. at all.. no errors, no spinning loading wheels. They do absolutely nothing.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I selected an answer for this question and for some reason that answer seems to have been deleted... so i'll have to answer it myself

The problem was with the browser, the exchange ECP doesn't work too well with Chrome and Microsoft Edge apparently. But if you use IE or Mozilla Firefox, you won't have any problem

Answer (score 0):

First - are you using the browser on the server itself, or on a workstation?
If on the server, ensure that you have IE SC turned off.
If on a workstation, ensure that it is fully patched, or try a different browser.

Simon.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I got this issue sorted yesterday, but for some reason the other guys answer has been deleted. It was indeed the browser